# About MFC, how to pass parameters to function OnPaint

Tags: c++, mfc

I write a override function OnPaint() in my own dialog, I don't know how to pass parameters to this function, it's called automatic. And I also wanna know that I used a PictureControl in my dialog, and load a picture file from disk using my own function( BitmapShow(UINT ctrlID, CString filePath) ), should I write code of loading picture in the override function OnPaint()? or copy this code segment into OnPaint()?

Comment: Well looking at the official doc I'm seeing `protected:
virtual void OnPaint(
 PaintEventArgs^ e
)` I believe there is an argument just there

Comment: @meneldal - That is not the MFC function and is not C++

Comment: Well that's an error on the MSDN website because they do list that one in the "C++" tab

Comment: @meneldal that's the .NET interface to C++, which is completely non-standard and in my opinion totally misguided. If you're going to use .NET you should use a language that's dedicated to it, like C#.

Comment: Well I don't use either and I didn't look in detailed to the category it was in

Comment: You can't pass variables to `OnPaint`, but you can declare global or class member variables, put them in `OnPaint`, modify these variable somewhere else, then call `Invalidate();` or you can make a separate paint function which accepts variables, call that function from anywhere. You can make use of `CClientDC dc(this)`.

Answer (score 3):

You can not change the definition of the OnPaint function. It is called only in response to the automatic WM_PAINT message. You can, and should, store any additional information needed by your OnPaint function as member variables, not as parameters.

To paint a picture on a picture control you should override the OnPaint of the picture control, not the dialog. This is done in a class you derive from CStatic.

Comment: Well, thank you very much! You mean that I should write the code of loading picture in OnPaint()?  My problem is that I can load a picture into the PictureControl using my own function, but if something else cover it, the image will disappear.

Comment: Yes, the disappear problem is why all painting should be done in OnPaint functions. But there is a separate OnPaint for the dialog and for the picture box.

Comment: How to add PictureControl's OnPaint? Use Class Wizard?

Comment: You could study an MFC tutorial or search this site for [MFC]subclass